# many to many. Get error during additional column saving to database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, many-to-many, pivot

Many to many relationships in the model

```
  public function drycleanings()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\drycleaning')
      ->withPivot('$cart_id','drycleaning_id','q_drycleaning_id');
    }
```

and

```
  public function carts()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\cart')
    ->withPivot('$cart_id','drycleaning_id','q_drycleaning_id');
  }
```

In the controller I am using

```
$cart->drycleanings()->attach($request->drycleaning_id,[$request->q_drycleaning_id]);
```

if gives me an error

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

Result of dd($request->all());

```
"drycleaning_id" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "3"
    1 => "4"
  ]
  "q_drycleaning_id" => array:58 [▼
    0 => "2"
    1 => "2"
    2 => null
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => null
    8 => null
    9 => null
    10 => null
  ]
```

Migration for cart_drycleaning table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCartDrycleaningTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cart_drycleaning', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('cart_id');
            $table->integer('drycleaning_id');
            $table->integer('q_drycleaning_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cart_drycleaning');
    }
}
```

If I use only `$cart->drycleanings()->attach($request->drycleaning_id);`
then cart_id and drycleaning_id gets stored into association/pivot table (table name: cart_drycleaning)

I am trying to save q_drycleaning_id (represent quantity of item) getting as input from user.

Is there any way I can only pass non-null values? or any other solution to save both into association table?

Comment: Laravel 4 or 5?

Comment: Looks like maybe you want `sync` and not `attach`?

Comment: Is this `$cart_id` a typo?

Comment: Its laravel 5.

I am not sure what to be there in withpivot but I need 3 columns in my table as cart_id, drycleaning_id, q_drycleaning_id